# Java connecting JDBC to Dynamic Web App

Tags: java, jdbc

I have run into a problem that I have been trying to figure out for days:

I added my driver: mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar to build path.
web-inf lib folder, apache tomcat lib folder. And also I have it in web app libaries.

However when I just run a main class and run it works, it is something to do with the web app?

This is my code:

This is the servlet class, that I use to connect to my database

```
package sql;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RegisterServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/register")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DbUtil sql = new DbUtil();

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RegisterServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String email = request.getParameter("email");

        String username = request.getParameter("username");

        String password = request.getParameter("password");


        if (sql.addToAccountToDatabase(username, password, email)) {



            System.out.println("Gongratz");

        } else {

            System.out.println("mhhh ?");
        }








    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */


}
```

this is the second class how i make connection

```
package sql;

import java.sql.*;

public class DbUtil {

    public Connection getConnection() {

        Connection connect = null;

        try {

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://hidden:3306/hidden";

            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "hidden", "hidden");
            return connect;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Cannot connect to database");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return connect;

    }

    public boolean addToAccountToDatabase(String username, String password, String email) {

        try {

            String query = "INSERT INTO Account (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pStat = getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            pStat.setString(1, username);
            pStat.setString(2, password);
            pStat.setString(3, email);
            pStat.executeUpdate();
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("User already exists");

            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        }

    }

}
```

And I get this error:

```
Cannot connect to database
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://192.185.227.214:3306/ratekas9_illegalminds
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sql.DbUtil.getConnection(DbUtil.java:15)
    at sql.DbUtil.addToAccountToDatabase(DbUtil.java:34)
    at sql.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
User already exists
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sql.DbUtil.addToAccountToDatabase(DbUtil.java:34)
    at sql.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
mhhh ?
```

Comment: Put yours jdbc driver jar in the server lib folder. ($CATALINA_HOME/lib) in case of Tomacat.

Comment: It has been added

Comment: Does it work now ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connectora-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Answer (score 1):

Because the String "jdbc:mysql" doesn't declare the driver Class itself, but only the name registered by a potential driver. You have to force the JVM to load the Driver class with a :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

before starting the JDBC connection.

Comment: In this case that is true, because the MySQL Connector/J is apart of the deployed application instead of the Tomcat as a whole, but in general using `Class.forName` to load the driver is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 steps to solve your problem:

1. Add this code before connection `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`
2. Add 'JConnector.jar' into your project and build path.
3. Don't try enter same person because there is error in stack trace "User all ready exist ".

Answer (score 0):

Adding the JAR file into your CLASSPATH (for compilation needs) / project's BUILDPATH and also under your project's WEB-INF/lib folder (for runtime references, i.e., when you deploy your application to an application server). For further reference, please go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384473/how-to-import-jdbc-driver-into-dynamic-web-project)

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

This is no longer required as per Official Java documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html), but it is a mandatory step if you are using prior versions of JDBC 4.0.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391496/is-class-forname-mechanism-needed) question can provide you lot many details on this regards.

Hope all these details help you resolve your issue!

Comment: Using `Class.forName` is also necessary if the driver is part of the deployed application, instead of the Tomcat system classpath.